# How do I control the margin top of a box amongst a group of boxes that have float:left on them?

Tags: html, css, css-float

CODE:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box box1">
    1
</div>
<div class="box box2">
    2
</div>
<div class="box box3">
    3
</div>
<div class="box box4">
    4
</div>
</div>

.container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 1000px;
}
.box {
    width: 470px;
    background: #333333;
}
.box1 {
    float: left;
    height: 498px;
        color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box2 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 589px;
        color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box3 {
    float: left;
    height: 446px;
    margin-top: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box4 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 529px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/hrAWn/

How do I make box # 3 move up so that the distance between it and box #1 is 20px, without using a negative top margin? I could achieve what I want using a negative margin but I don't like using negative margins so I wanted to see if there is a way I can move it up without using a negative margin.  Any ideas on how to accomplish it or do I have to use negative top?

Comment: Do you have any flexibility in your HTML? Even with a negative margin, you will have trouble if the height of box #2 varies.  Are your height values for illustrative purposes or the definite values for the final layout?

Comment: You could use JavaScript to move things around, or negative margins as you mentioned, however using just floats won't allow you to do that as the specs state: "The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document."

Comment: @marcaudent they are definite so I have to keep the heights intact.

Comment: If your heights and widths are as specified, I would simply use absolute positioning to get the arrangement that is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change box #2 to float:right.